# Wrapping Image tag inside a TouchableHighlight tag is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touchablehighlight

I am a beginner in React native so I'm sorry if that may sound silly but whenever i wrap the Image tag in a TouchableHightlight tag the Image disappears completely from my screen

How can i solve this, Please?

```
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log("img tapped")}>
        <Image
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            right: 10,
            top: 15,
          }}
          source={require("../assets/task/more.png")}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
```

[image: My App]